# Bug em sequenciador de nomes

Tags: javascript, html5

Desenvolvi um sistema que escreve, de modo sequenciado, uma frase dentro da minha `div` e, após alguns segundos, ele substitui o texto por um outro pré programado. Ele funciona normalmente, mas, caso eu mude a guia por algum tempo e retorne a guia onde o sequenciador está, ele simplesmente enlouquece juntando os 3 textos em um só.

Alguém sabe como poderia resolver isso ou me explicar o motivo que isso acontece?

```js
var div = document.getElementById('log');
var texto = ['Arroz preto Arroz preto Arroz preto Arroz preto Arroz preto Arroz preto Arroz preto Arroz preto Arroz preto'
, 'Milho e farinha com chibe literalmente'
, 'Um prato de trigo para tres trigres tristes'];
var fundo = ["img/imagem4.jpg", "img/imagem2.jpg", "img/imagem1.png"]

function escrever(str, el) {
    $('#log').html('');
    var char = str.split('').reverse();
    var typer = setInterval(function () {
        if (!char.length) return clearInterval(typer);
        var next = char.pop();
        el.innerHTML += next;
    }, 80);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getScript("assets/plugins/backstretch/jquery.backstretch.min.js", function () {
            $(".fullscreen-static-image1").backstretch([
                imagem,
            ], {
                duration: 8000,
                fade: 400
            });
        });
    });
}
repetir();
setInterval(function () {
    repetir()
}, 28000);

function repetir() {
    escrever(texto[0], div, fundo[0]);

    setTimeout(function () {
        escrever(texto[1], div, fundo[1])
    }, 10000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        escrever(texto[2], div, fundo[3])
    }, 14000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        escrever(texto[3], div, fundo[3])
    }, 21000);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Qual seria o `texto[3]`?

Comment: E o problema está nos tempos que está utilizando. Você não está levando em consideração o tamanho de cada texto e o tempo que levará para escrevê-lo completamente antes de iniciar o próximo.

Comment: Eu coloquei os tempos considerando o tamanho das mensagens, tanto se eu ficar na pagina por muito tempo as mensagens funcionam normalmente. mas quando mudo de guia e passo uns 30 segundos nessa guia e retorno para a guia do sequenciador ele buga, fica um tempo bugado e depois retorna ao original sem bug

Comment: Você viu seu código executando aqui no site? Já na primeira transição do primeiro para o segundo texto as mensagens se confundem, sem contar que você está querendo exibir o `texto[3]` que nem existe.

Comment: Eu troquei os texto original para um aleatório para exemplificação. ja alterei para a escrita ser menor que o tempo abordado, mas agora ajeitei para poder avaliar o problema melhor